# Hibernate ERROR: Unknown column in delete query (mapping many2many via embedded)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 entities (User and Group) in a many-to-many relantionship. Therefore, I created the table IsIn, which is composed by userId, groupId (composed primary key) and 2 extra fields (typeId and isBlocked). I followed Vlad Mihalcea's tutorial on how to map the entities in such a situation -> [see here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/)

However, when I try to delete a user or a group, it doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Unknown column 'groups0_.user_userId' in 'field list'

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

I will post below my classes.

**UserGroupId (Embedded)**

```
package Embedded;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

@Embeddable
public class UserGroupId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "userId")
    private int userId;

    @Column(name = "groupId")
    private int groupId;

    public UserGroupId() {}

    public UserGroupId(int userId, int groupId) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;

        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        UserGroupId that = (UserGroupId) o;
        return Objects.equals(userId, that.userId) &&
                Objects.equals(groupId, that.groupId);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(userId, groupId);
    }
}
```

**IsIn**

```
package entity;

import Embedded.UserGroupId;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "isin")
public class IsIn {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserGroupId id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("userId")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("groupId")
    private Group group;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "typeId")
    private UserType typeId;

    @Column(name = "isBlocked", nullable = false)
    private boolean isBlocked;

    public IsIn() {}

    public IsIn(User user, Group group) {
        this.user = user;
        this.group = group;
        this.id = new UserGroupId(user.getUserId(), group.getGroupId());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;

        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        IsIn that = (IsIn) o;
        return Objects.equals(user, that.user) &&
                Objects.equals(group, that.group);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(user, group);
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public Group getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public void setGroup(Group group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    public UserType getTypeId() {
        return typeId;
    }

    public void setTypeId(UserType typeId) {
        this.typeId = typeId;
    }

    public boolean isBlocked() {
        return isBlocked;
    }

    public void setBlocked(boolean blocked) {
        isBlocked = blocked;
    }
}
```

**User**

```
package entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "`user`")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "userId" ,unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int userId;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "user",
            cascade={CascadeType.ALL},
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<IsIn> groups = new ArrayList<>();

    @Column(name = "customerName", nullable = false)
    private String customerName;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "is_active", nullable = false)
    private boolean is_active;

    @Column(name = "notificationType", nullable = false)
    private String notificationType;

    @Column(name = "create_date", nullable = false)
    private String create_date;

    public User() { }

    public User(String customerName, String password, String email, boolean is_active, String notificationType, String create_date) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.is_active = is_active;
        this.notificationType = notificationType;
        this.create_date = create_date;
    }

    public void addGroup(Group group) {
        IsIn isIn = new IsIn(this, group);
        groups.add(isIn);
    }

    public void removeGroup(Group group) {
        for (Iterator<IsIn> iterator = groups.iterator();
             iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            IsIn isIn = iterator.next();

            if (isIn.getUser().equals(this) &&
                    isIn.getGroup().equals(group)) {
                iterator.remove();
                isIn.setUser(null);
                isIn.setGroup(null);
            }
        }
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public boolean isIs_active() {
        return is_active;
    }

    public void setIs_active(boolean is_active) {
        this.is_active = is_active;
    }

    public String getNotificationType() {
        return notificationType;
    }

    public void setNotificationType(String notificationType) {
        this.notificationType = notificationType;
    }

    public String getCreate_date() {
        return create_date;
    }

    public void setCreate_date(String create_date) {
        this.create_date = create_date;
    }
}
```

**Group**

```
package entity;

import org.hibernate.annotations.NaturalIdCache;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "`group`")
@NaturalIdCache
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "groupId")
    private int groupId;

    @Column(name = "groupName")
    private String groupName;

    @Column(name = "create_date", nullable = false)
    private String create_date;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "created_by", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "isPrivate")
    private boolean isPrivate;

    public Group() { }

    public Group(String groupName, String create_date, User user, boolean isPrivate) {
        this.groupName = groupName;
        this.create_date = create_date;
        this.user = user;
        this.isPrivate = isPrivate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;

        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        Group group = (Group) o;
        return Objects.equals(groupId, group.getGroupId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() { return Objects.hash(groupId); }

    public int getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }

    public void setGroupId(int groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }

    public String getGroupName() {
        return groupName;
    }

    public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
        this.groupName = groupName;
    }

    public String getCreate_date() {
        return create_date;
    }

    public void setCreate_date(String create_date) {
        this.create_date = create_date;
    }

    public boolean isPrivate() {
        return isPrivate;
    }

    public void setPrivate(boolean aPrivate) {
        isPrivate = aPrivate;
    }

    public User getCreated_by() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setCreated_by(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

And here is my delete method (which works for other entities, except for User and Group).

```
public static void deleteUserById(int userId) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        try{
            session.beginTransaction();
            User u = UserDAO.getUserById(userId);
            session.delete(u);
            session.flush();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (HibernateException he) {
            he.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }
```

Any kind of help is highly appreciated, thank you for your time.

**Table DDLs**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chatapp`.`user` (
 `userId` INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `customerName` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 `password` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL unique,
 `is_active` boolean NOT NULL,
 `notificationType` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 `create_date` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`userId`),
 INDEX `userId_idx` (`userId` ASC)
 );

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chatapp`.`group` (
 `groupId` INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `groupName` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
 `create_date` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 `created_by` INT NOT NULL,
 `isPrivate` boolean NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`groupId`),
 INDEX `groupId_idx` (`groupId` ASC),
 FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`) REFERENCES `user` (`userId`)
 );

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chatapp`.`isin` (
 `userId` INT NOT NULL,
 `groupId` INT NOT NULL,
 `typeId` INT NOT NULL,
 `isBlocked` boolean NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`userId`,`groupId`),
 FOREIGN KEY (`userId`)  REFERENCES `user` (`userId`),
 FOREIGN KEY (`groupId`) REFERENCES `group` (`groupId`),
 FOREIGN KEY (`typeId`)  REFERENCES `usertype` (`typeId`)
);
```

**Full StackTrace**
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSEj6.png)

**Complete Database design**
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp9nv.png)

Comment: Your Database structure does not match your mapping. How did you create the DB?

Comment: I've posted only the entities relevant for my question, not the entire mapping. But, I would like to hear what mistakes you've discovered so far in my attempt to map these entities.

Comment: There are two ways to find out what the differences are. 1) generate the Database schema from the Entity Mappings 2) generate the Entities from the Database. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Just something that I just noticed: There are JoinColumn annotatoin missing on the IsIn entity for the ManyToOne relatinships that are part of the ID

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I've changed MapsId to JoinColumn and now it works, thanks :)

Comment: Great. I added this as answer and would be happy if you can mark this as the correct answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @JoinColumn annotations are missing in the IsIn class.

It should look like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "isin")
public class IsIn {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserGroupId id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn("userId")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn("groupId")
    private Group group;
```